# Reducing Run time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two dataframes. If the postcodes from both dataframes match then the corresponding ResidenceID (from dataframe 2) should be put into dataframe 1.I put this code together and it runs and gives me what I need but I need to simplify it so that the code runs faster. My dataset is 400k rows long and has 2 columns. Currently the code takes 4.5 mins to run. How can I make it run faster.Any help much appreciated :)

```
import time
start= time.time()
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('Residence_CCG_Check_M9.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', dtype={'Postcode': str})
df2 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='East of England', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df3 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='London Commissioning Region', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df4 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='Midlands Commissioning Region', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df5 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='North East and Yorkshire Commis', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df6 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='North West Commissioning Region', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df7 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='South East Commissioning Region', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df8 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='South West Commissioning Region', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df9 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='Channel Islands and Isle of Man', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
df10 = pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx',sheet_name='Wales, Scotland and Northern Ir', usecols=['Postcode', 'CCG'], dtype={'Postcode': str})
dfAll = pd.concat([df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10])
merged_df = pd.merge(df1,dfAll, on='Postcode', how= 'left')
merged_df = merged_df.rename(columns={'CCG_y':'CCG'})
merged_df.to_excel(excel_writer="ResidenceCheck.xlsx", index=False, header=True)
end=time.time()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: Are the sheets read from the second file all the sheets in that spreadsheet? If so you can use `pd.concat(pd.read_excel('CCG_Codes.xlsx', sheet_name=None, ... ))` to read and concat all the sheets in one line. Otherwise, use `sheet_name=[<all sheet names>]`

Comment: Have you profiled it to see which line is the slowest? How many rows are in `df1` and `dfAll`?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal thanks I tried that and it got the runtime down to 81seconds.

Comment: @CodeDifferent I haven't profiled it. I'll try do that. df1 has 200k rows and dfAll has around 400k rows.